# Timezone formula field- why doesn't my exception line work?

Tags: formula, timezone

The formula below works perfectly, except the part in bold. I want to add an exception to assigning time zones by state for this one particular city (for now). I have been tweaking it for a while now to no avail so need some fresh eyes.

```
IF(CASE(ShippingState , 'Yukon',1,'British Columbia',1 , 'California', 1, 'Nevada', 1,'Oregon', 1, 'Washington', 1, 0) >=1, "Pacific Standard Time (PST)", null)+

**IF(CASE(ShippingState,'Oregon',1), IF(CASE(ShippingCity,'Ontario'),1, 0) >=1, "Mountain Standard Time (MST)", null)+**

IF(CASE(ShippingState ,'Northwest Territories',1,'Alberta',1 ,'Arizona', 1, 'Colorado', 1,'Idaho', 1, 'Montana', 1, 'New Mexico', 1, 'Utah', 1, 'Wyoming', 1, 0) >= 1, "Mountain Standard Time (MST)", null)+

IF(CASE(ShippingState ,'Saskatchewan',1,'Manitoba',1,'Alabama', 1, 'Arkansas', 1, 'Illinois', 1, 'Iowa', 1,'Kansas', 1,'Kentucky',1, 'Louisiana', 1,'Minnesota', 1,'Mississippi', 1,'Missouri', 1,'Nebraska', 1,'North Dakota', 1, 'Oklahoma', 1,'South Dakota',1,'Texas',1,'Tennessee', 1,'Wisconsin', 1, 0) >= 1, "Central Standard Time (CST)", null)+

IF(CASE(ShippingState , 'Nunavut',1,'Ontario',1,'Quebec',1,'New Brunswick',1,'Nova Scotia',1,'Connecticut', 1, 'Delaware', 1,'Florida',1,'Georgia',1,'Indiana',1, 'Maine', 1, 'Maryland', 1, 'Massachusetts', 1,'Michigan', 1, 'New Hampshire', 1, 'New Jersey', 1, 'New York', 1, 'North Carolina', 1, 'Ohio', 1, 'Pennsylvania', 1, 'Rhode Island', 1, 'South Carolina', 1, 'Vermont', 1, 'Virginia', 1, 'West Virginia', 1,'Washington, D.C.',1, 0) >= 1,"Eastern Standard Time (EST)", null)+

IF(CASE(ShippingState , 'Alaska', 1, 0) >=1, "Alaska Standard Time (AKST)", null)+

IF(CASE(ShippingState , 'Hawaii', 1, 0) >=1, "Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time (HST)", NULL)
```

Comment: make sure you properly format your code when creating posts, as it can become hard to read. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sfdc fox is right, that line should work. However Salesforce is very picky in regards to limiting number of characters for formulas. You'll likely run into a character issue unless you rewrite the syntax. I changed the following:

- Removed CASE() statements and went with stacked IFs() to save space
- Put the exception in the beginning for any state/city combo (1st match will trump all other matches)

>

```
/*Exceptions*/
IF(AND(ShippingState="Oregon",ShippingCity="Ontario"),"Ontario Exception Here",

/*State Rules*/
IF(CONTAINS("Yukon:British Columbia:California:Nevada:Oregon:Washington",ShippingState),"Pacific Standard Time (PST)",

IF(CONTAINS("Northwest Territories:Alberta:Arizona:Colorado:Idaho:Montana:New Mexico:Utah:Wyoming",ShippingState),"Mountain Standard Time (MST)",

IF(CONTAINS("Saskatchewan:Manitoba:Alabama:Arkansas:Illinois:Iowa:Kansas:Kentucky:Louisiana:Minnesota:Mississippi:Missouri:Nebraska:North Dakota:Oklahoma:South Dakota:Texas:Tennessee:Wisconsin",ShippingState),"Central Standard Time (CST)",

IF(CONTAINS("Nunavut:Ontario:Quebec:New Brunswick:Nova Scotia:Connecticut:Delaware:Florida:Georgia:Indiana:Maine:Maryland:Massachusetts:Michigan:New Hampshire:New Jersey:New York:North Carolina:Ohio:Pennsylvania:Rhode Island:South Carolina:Vermont:Virginia:West Virginia:Washington,D.C.",ShippingState),"Eastern Standard Time (EST)",

IF(CONTAINS("Alaska",ShippingState),"Alaska Standard Time (AKST)",

IF(CONTAINS("Hawaii",ShippingState),"Hawaii-Aleutian Standard Time (HST)",null

)))))))
```

>

Comment: Thanks, @rmarq! your edits made a world of difference in my character counts. I appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 1):

IF statement expected the state field to simultaneously be two different values because of misplaced parentheses, and the extra if/case bit.

Here's the corrected version of that line.

```
IF(CASE(ShippingState,'Oregon',1,'Ontario',1, 0)=1, "Mountain Standard Time (MST)", null)+
```

As a general note, it's not necessary to use >=, since the only possible values are 1 or 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry about the lack of formatting. I added your code and am getting the following: 

"Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'CASE()'. Expected 6, received 7" 
I don't understand what the issue could be. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @SMarq Yes, there was actually an extra parameter, as I didn't delete enough. I went ahead and fixed this. The new version should compile.

Comment: Oh I see thank you. 
The only issue that I need the statement to be based on the city of Ontario, Oregon. This statement does not call out the shipping city. How can I do this?

Comment: @SMarq Sounds like you meant to do `IF(AND(ShippingState='Oregon',ShippingCity='Ontario'),'Mountain Standard Time (MST)', null)+`.